# Small rectangle probability

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, gaussian

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mu$ be a centered Gaussian measure on it. Also, let the eigenpair corresponding to $\mu$ be $(i^{-\alpha} , e_i)$ with $\alpha > 1$. Assume we have a ball of radius k around 0. Let a "rectangle" inside this ball be defined as 
 $\prod_i [-r_ie_i, r_ie_i]$ such that $\sum_i r_i^2 \leq k^2$. How do we estimate (a bound by below) the maximum measure such a rectangle can take?
In my attempts, it came down to minimising $\sum_i \frac{i^{-\alpha/2}e^{-i^{\alpha} r_i^2/2}}{r_i}$ given $\sum_i r_i^2 \leq k^2$.
How do we proceed from here? Any other method or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, atleast can we show that this maximum, say f(k) is such that $\frac{f(k)}{\mu\{x : \left\|x\right\| < k \}} > C > 0$ where C is independent of k.

Comment: Is the place dead? :S

Comment: It is a narrow question...